# R Shiny: getting error "no loop for break/next, jumping to top level"

Tags: r, loops, shiny

I'm trying to create an R Shiny page that shows a life expectancy graph for the United States and an additional country to be selected by the user. The code runs and Shiny does what I expected, but when I close it, R shows the following two errors:

> Listening on http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx
>
> no loop for break/next, jumping to top level
>
> no loop for break/next, jumping to top level

I've found other questions about this error in R, but they were using a *for* loop, which I am not using (at least not consciously, I imagine Shiny has a loop for the reactive functions?)

**Why does it show those two errors?**

Thanks!

Below is my code:

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(dslabs)
data(gapminder)

countries <- unique(gapminder$country)

# Define UI
ui <- fluidPage(
    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        selectInput("country", label= "Select a country to compare to", choices = countries,
selected = "Spain", multiple = F)
      ),
      mainPanel(plotOutput(outputId = "linegraph")
      )
    )
)

# Define server
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$linegraph <- renderPlot({ggplot(aes(x = year, y = life_expectancy),
              data = filter(gapminder, country == "United States")) +
      scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(40, 85, 5), limits = c(40, 85)) +
      geom_line(color = "black") +
      ggtitle("US life expectancy") +
      geom_line( color = "blue", data = filter(gapminder, country == input$country))
  })
}


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Bonus question: is there an easy way to debug Shiny code? How can I know what line in my code is generating the error?

Comment: What version of `shiny` are you running? I cannot replicate that error. Also what package are you getting `data(gapminder)` from? In the `gapminder` package the column is called `lifeExp`, not `life_expectancy`.

Comment: Which IDE are you using? RStudio? Make sure you don't have any breakpoints set up: Debug->Clear All Breakpoins

Comment: I'm running version 1.4.0 of Shiny on RStudio, but for some reason I'm not getting the error anymore (go figure).
Also, I was getting the gapminder data from the dslabs package.(one line above).